# Parse 0 size protobuf message as Any and UnpackTo type

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, message, named-pipes

I ran into an issue with deserializing 0-length protobuf messages.

First I read the length of the message and then the message itself:

```
// Runs on input read thread
bool readInputMessage(google::protobuf::Any& outMessage, NamedPipe& pipe)
{
    int numBytes;
    pipe.readInt32(numBytes);
    if(!pipe.blockForAsyncIO())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read message size from pipe" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[numBytes]);
    if(numBytes > 0)
    {
        pipe.readBytes(numBytes, buffer.get());
        if(!pipe.blockForAsyncIO())
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read message from pipe" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return outMessage.ParseFromArray(buffer.get(), numBytes);
}
```

Next, I try to unpack the Any message into a concrete type:

```
template<class T>
bool parseMessage(google::protobuf::Any& anyMessage, T& outMessage)
{
    if(!anyMessage.UnpackTo(&outMessage))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to parse message" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

The incoming message looks like this:

```
message SetupMessage {
    bool isHunter = 1;
}
```

and when `isHunter` is set to `false` the message is serialized with 0 bytes length. The problem is that `UnpackTo()` returns false and is not able to unpack the empty Any message into the SetupMessage type. Is there anything i can do to help it parse the message correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your message SetupMessage seems defective as each field must be annotated with one of optional, repeated or required. It is unclear how you feed that to protobuf compiler without getting rejected.

Comment: I am using proto3 syntax if that helps

Comment: From the protobuf documentation, there can be up to one ‘singular’ field which doesn’t need an explicit specifier. It also states that if the singular field has a default value it is not serialised which matches my observations. I could set it to be a required field and it might potentially solve the issue but parsing should work for singular fields with default values as well so I assume there is a mistake in my code.